# where is the generated code of "Qt Signals/Slots editor"?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

QtCreator 2.7.2 ,I use the Qt Creator design a connection and i can see it in the file *.ui ,but I can't find it in the generated file ui_*.h after build, where is it ? I'm curious.

Comment: there is a search function in Operating System, isn't it?

Comment: Look for the .moc files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there, usually by the end of setupUi method. Just look better.

For instance, this chunk in the .ui

```
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>checkBox</sender>
   <signal>toggled(bool)</signal>
   <receiver>checkBox_2</receiver>
   <slot>setChecked(bool)</slot>
  </connection>
 </connections>
```

Results in

```
QObject::connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), checkBox_2, SLOT(setChecked(bool)));
```

in the generated header.

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that some versions of Qt/MOC will invoke a call to [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) - particularly for the UI portion

Comment: It's not "some versions of Qt/MOC". All headers generated by `uic` will have such call, again usually around the end of the `setupUi` generated function.

Answer (score 0):

The meta-object compiler (moc) generates the glue code for signals and slots. The UI editor just handles the connections and emits the necessary stuff to the ui file. Uic compiles these things into c++ headers which are then used my moc.